# change Docker Container Variabels

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a container which inherits some unwanted environment variables form my  Mac system,

Because I'm in Iran and Docker hub is banned Iranians to pull the images we have to set proxy to pull images. after I pull images and disable proxy, I tried to build a container,

my **Dockerfile** is :

```
FROM python:3.6
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /config
ADD /config/requirements.txt /config/
RUN pip install -r /config/requirements.txt
RUN mkdir /src
WORKDIR /src
CMD nohup scrapyd &
```

and my **docker-compose.yml** file contains

```
version: '3'
services:
  dj-service:
    build: .
    container_name: ms01
    command: bash -c "./run_django.sh"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
    expose:
      - "8000"
    ports:
      - "6800:6800"
```

the container created correctly but when I wanted to `curl 127.0.0.1:6800` in the ms01 container faced with a kind of proxy error

`Connection Refused ....     Generated by <i>COW 0.9.8</i> <br />
        Host <i>prometheu`

and after some investigation, I tried to inspect ms01 container with `docker inspect ms01` and saw a strange thing

```
        "Env": [
            "HTTP_PROXY=X.X.X.X:7777",
            "http_proxy=X.X.X.X:7777",
            "PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
            "LANG=C.UTF-8",
            "GPG_KEY=0D96DF4D4110E5C43FBFB17F2D347EA6AA65421D",
            "PYTHON_VERSION=3.6.6",
            "PYTHON_PIP_VERSION=10.0.1",
            "PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1"
        ],
```

While I haven't set this enviroment variables in docker-compose or `.env` file, **my question is  where and why this data are inherited ? and how can I remove this enviroment variables without rebuild my image and container?**

I've checked my  `printenv` result in my host machine and there was no such config there.

**notice** : "X.X.X.X:7777" is my Http proxy which I'd set to pull the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Containers will get the proxy settings from the docker engine:

> When you create or start new containers, the [http proxy] environment variables are set automatically within the container.

See https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/ for how to configure the proxy on the docker engine.

Comment: Yup, after removing docker GUI proxy settings and restart the docker and rebuild the container they vanished.I've lost one hour to find out it ,  late answer but you right.

Answer (score 1):

> where and why this data are inherited ?

They are inherited from your base image `python:3.6`. See the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/7a794688c7246e7eff898f5288716a3e7dc08484/3.6/stretch/Dockerfile#L21-L22)

> how can I remove this enviroment variables without rebuild my image and container?

Currently you can not. For more information, see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/3465), not resolved since 2014

Comment: Are you sure `  "HTTP_PROXY=X.X.X.X:7777",
            "http_proxy=X.X.X.X:7777"` are inherited from the python3.6 image? I don't think so, because they were my docker configuration while I've pulled the images. thank you for time.

Comment: No, HTTP_PROXY and http_proxy are not inherited from `python:3.6`. PATH, LANG, GPG_KEY, PYTHON_VERSION, and PYTHON_PIP_VERSION are inherited.

Comment: it might, my problem was about connection refusing ( as I mentioned in the question) .